# Cut a url OR a domain name

Tags: regex, linux, bash, cut

I have a list of random url

```
www.google.com
http://www.google.com
http://sub.microsoft.com/mydoc.pdf
www.microosft.com.my/doc.pdf
https://sub.mydomain.com/mydoc.pdf
sub.domain.com/mydoc.pdf
```

My goal is to get the url (with http or https if are) and to remove everything after the Top-level domain name

```
www.google.com
http://www.google.com
http://sub.microsoft.com
www.microosft.com
https://sub.mydomain.com
sub.domain.com
```

I tried to cut everything after / but not correct.
Do you have any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: URL parsing functionality is built in to many scripting languages - is it a requirement that you use the shell?

Comment: Yeah I have to ... That's the problem

Comment: There's a good answer using shell tools that you should be able to adapt to your needs in the linked question.